# Strip out additional new line character from text file

Tags: file, text, file-io, newline

Few columns in the text file has '\n' or '\r' values in the text file and we want to get rid of any such additional characters from the file.

The text file might have something like this:

```
A|B|C|D|E
1|2|3 \n 4|5
9|8|7|6|5|4
```

Now when I process the file in my application I process it by the new line characters and the extra new line doesnt help my case

How can I do the same? Doing this in the application does not make sense to me.. I need a way to strip these characters

Answer (score 0):

You really can't.

This is why: In the end, a text file is nothing more than a bunch of 1's and 0's that represent characters in a line. Some Characters are created to help format the text for a text reader/editor like `/n` or newline. So to a computer, there is no difference in writing the character `'/n'` and hitting enter, thus writing the character `'/n.'` The computer has no concept of "white space" like you see in a text editor when viewing this file.

Depending on what you need to do with this text file, you could surround the newline character with quotes or something and tell the program to exclude what's inside it, but even that is a little weird.

I recommend finding a different way to do what you want to do.